# Java interface best practice

Tags: java, interface

I have two objects in the following way

```
public class ObjectA {
 int id ;
 String name;
}

 public class objectB {
  Long id;
  String name;
 }
```

I want to be able to create an interface 'AnObject' that will be implemented by these two objects. How would this interface look like?

```
public interface AnObject {
  public <type?> getId() ;
  public String getName();
}
```

What should the type be in the getter for ID?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, do not name it `Object`. [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is Java's implicit base class for all other classes. Technically, you could name your interface `Object` as long as you do not place it in the package `java.lang`, but that would be highly misleading.

To provide different return types for `getId()` in `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`, use generics:

```
public interface MyObject<T> {
  T getId();
  String getName();
}

public class ObjectA implements MyObject<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer getId() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "A";
  }
}

public class ObjectB implements MyObject<Long> {
  @Override
  public Long getId() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "B";
  }
}
```

If `getId()` always returns a number, you could also define `MyObject` as `MyObject<T extends Number>`. Note that you cannot use the native types `int` and `long` with generics; you have to use the boxed types `Integer` and `Long`.

Comment: Thanks Robin, thats useful. The keyword 'Object' was just for example

Comment: We can improve this solution by adding `public interface MyObject<T extends Number>` as we expect type `T` to be a number.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen You're right; have a look at the last paragraph of my answer. ;)

Comment: I see. I must have missed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your id is always a number.

If the user of your getter `getId()` doesn't (or shouldn't) care for the actual type of the return value you could also use `Number` directly, without generics. It depends on the context if you want to use generics or not. An advantage of *not* using generics in this case would be that you don't have to define the actual type of the id, which makes the calling code less coupled with the implementation of `MyObject`.

```
public interface AnObject {
    public Number getId() ;
    public String getName();
}
```

The code that calls this, will not know the actual type of the Id. However they can still be sure that it is a number and can call things like `Number.doubleValue()` or `Number.longValue()` as the calling code requires.